# ListView Intent On Item Click Listener stop Application Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I have `ListView`. I want to click on item and change the activity. `ListView` works appropriately but when I click on any item, application stops and closes.

```
ListView myListViewOfSongs;
String[] people;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myListViewOfSongs = findViewById(R.id.songs);
    people = new String[]{
            "Mike Strong",
            "Jennifer Anniston",
            "Tom Bennet",
            "Leander Paes",
            "Liam Nesson",
            "George Clooney",
            "Barack Obama",
            "Steve Jobs",
            "Larry Page",
            "Sergey Brin",
            "Steve Wozniak"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,people);
    myListViewOfSongs.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myListViewOfSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Maybe share the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your question . You have used `getApplicationContext()` to start Intent. Please replace
`getApplicationContext()` with `context`

**Replace code**

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class));
```

**To**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**OR**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use getApplicationContext() when starting Intent. You should replace it with context of your activity.